# How to get objects from firebase firestore snapshots (React Hooks)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am using Firebase Firestore in ReactJS and wants to fetch data, How can i set the entire recived data into post?

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])    
useEffect(() => {
    database
        .firestore()
        .collection("news")
        .get()
        .then(snapshots => {
            setState(snapshots.docs)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
})



return(
    <div>
        <div className="px-2">
            <div className="flex -mx-2">
                {state.map(data => <span>{data.title}<span>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the .collection You would do something like this if you're looking to monitor it with snapshot.

```
      .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        const news = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          news.push(doc.data());
        });
        setState(news);
```

A one time call can be done with

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the second parameter to the useEffect method otherwise, it will be called infinite times.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ....
}, [])
```